# file_get_contents with HTTP Basic Authorization based on the network connection

Tags: php, file-get-contents, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I am using the file_get_contents() with HTTP basic Authorization to get the content from my `$url`:

```
$url = "http://example.com";
$cred = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s', base64_encode('username:password'));
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => $cred
    )
);
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
```

When I have the correct username and Password in my code, I can get the content from the url perfectly fine, no matter which network connection I have been connected to.

But, I want to make it based on the network connection. For instance, if I connected to my LAN, it can get the content from the url without asking for username and password, but if I connected to any other network connection, user should be asked to enter the username and password.

If I am not mistaken, I need to use `HTTP authentication with PHP`, however I do not know that how can I integrate it into my code and make it executed based on the network connection but not always.

I will really appreciate, if anyone can help me in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is to detect on which network you are connected. You have to run `ipconfig` or `ifconfig`, maybe even the `route` command to check/parse on which network you are connected. If you have solved this problem you can use a simple `if ()` statement to include the username/password or not.